# Disable Inline CSS from Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Rendering a site on server with angular universal results in the proper page, so far so good. But the source code of the pages is overloaded with inline css (more than 50% of the document > 500kb) which results in slow download time e.g. on slow connections. I know that the inline css should reduce flickering and a fast first paint, any way the donwload times adds up that much the technique is not worth the traffic.

Is there any option/configuration to disable or dramatically reduce the inlined css?

Setup:

- Angular 8.2.14
- Angular Universal 8.1.1

Comment: Does that help? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21026

Comment: i dont think it matches. TransferState Objects seens to me an other part than the generated css. These Objects are disabled widely and do not hurt us any more

Comment: I was referring to BEFORE_APP_SERIALIZED

Comment: Do you have some more hints, what you mean exactly? How do i save the document before css is bound that way? I have no clue how to solve the problem with this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there is no solution i was thinking about. I did not thought that there is a strong binding between the DOM elements and the generated css, but unfortunatly it is (e.g. `.header-wrapper[_ngcontent-sc1]`).

Removing the css results in a page with nearly no css. rebuilding it via css in some days to week of work. So the aproach should be to reduce the css binding to get a lighter document structure and after that disable the binding/generation if there is any anymore.